# Automating Database count, database name, database creation_date using powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I want to get three informations ( db_count, db_name, db_creation_date )  from multiple sql servers which are in different domains using powershell script.
I need the result in consolidated csv file.

Can anyone guide me how to start and move further to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not sure what db_count is personally unless you're getting the count across the instance. However, these can be obtained by querying [sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the `name` and the `create_date`. That's pretty straight forward.

You'd need the sql commands to open connections to each server, so security is going to be tough here. I'm sure there isn't a single user across all instances that you can use so you'll have to work with the DBA for each on that.

Since they are on different domains, I'd suspect you'd want to use a VPN or something to not pass all of this information in the clear, so you'd need to work with the networking teams to even get access to the domains.

And the list will go on.

Comment: I assume the query would look something like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS db_count
 , name AS db_name
 , create_date AS db_creation_date  FROM sys.databases 
WHERE [name] NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')`

Comment: Thanks Jacob, This query is working I will embed it in powershell, hope there also it will work.